# Ethernet connection speed is still the same after a change in speed and duplex option to 1Gbps full duplex

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, speed

I discovered that the Ethernet speed is only 100Mbps when I checked on “Open Network & Internet Settings > Ethernet > Change adapter options > Double-clicking the Network Connection”

> [image: Screenshot.]

I'm using CAT6 as my Ethernet cable and already configured the Properties of the Ethernet connection into 1Gbps Full Duplex, see image below, and then the connection was reset and I'm still seeing the same 100Mbps value for speed.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Our home network is using an ZTE ZXHN F670L router which was provided by our ISP, and I'm not seeing any manuals from the internet regarding all the options on the admin panel so I'm not sure if it should be configured on the router or in the pc. Any ideas?

By the way here's a screenshot of Ethernet in the admin panel. I'm using Intel NUC I5 11th gen.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Dumb question, but can it also be done for wireless connection?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation I'm finding online for the ZTE F670L is inconsistent, but in several places it says that only one of its LAN ports is gigabit capable, and the other three are only 100Mbit capable.

So I guess make sure you're connecting to the only gigabit-capable port.

Comment: This [manual PDF](http://ztegpon.cz/pdf/ZXHN%20F670L%20datasheet.pdf) — in English but on a Czech site — says under “Overview”: “The ZXHN F670L is an AC1200 dual band Gigabit Premium triple-play GPON gateway. It comes with 1GE&3FE LAN ports…” But then there is utterly no indication of which is the “GE” (Gigabit Ethernet) port versus the “FE” (Fast Ethernet) ports. Weird.

Comment: Not asked, but OP can perhaps get a 4-port GB switch, connect the switch to the router on the GB port and then the rest of the LAN to the switch.

Comment: @Yorik True. But many people don’t want another brick added to a setup that should work without issue. The fact that the manuals and references online for the ZTE ZXHN F670L all send mixed messages about Ethernet port speed, my gut tells me a better tact would be to just get a better standalone router and let the ZTE ZXHN F670L be used in bridge mode just as a modem to connect to the ISP.